# Python trigger file change events

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I have a set of 100 files which are created by an application. The files are updated dynamically not in the sequential manner. Using Python, I am trying to read the files. However, I don't know which file is getting updated at what time.

I don't want to every time loop through each and every file to check which files are updated at the instance. I can create multiple processes/threads  for triggering to the main process which file got updated. Is there any other way like the file updation can notify the main python process so that only those files are read??

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try the python module "watchdog". It will start a file or folder observer which can be used to start functions on file/folder change.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog

The example below will watch a folder and notify every change to the files in it. If you want only particular events please see the documentation.
https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class EventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print event


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "/PATH/TO/YOUR/FOLDER"
    event_handler = EventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: All the files are not created in the same folder. They are created in different folder like 100. So do I need to create 100 observers as such??

Comment: Are those folders all around your filesystem, or are they all in one application specific top dir?

Comment: They are all having a specific top directory.

Comment: Then you can just set the top dir as path. With the `recursive` parameter of the schedule method, all dirs below the given path are also observed.

Comment: if I want to observe every single file without using the top directory then do I have to create multiple observers for that??

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure you have to do that. But a single observer is not taking many resources, so it should be not a big deal

Comment: I will have to try that and check if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `event.src_path` to your main process as file gets modified (handle it in `on_modified` event of Event handler).